# Acrobat 10: Run Javascript whenever a different item is highlighted in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I would like to know if its possible if I can have javascript change the values of other fields based on a user highlighting different options in a dropdown box before actually selecting the option?

So let's the user uses the mouse or arrows key to navigate through the list, before selecting an item. I would like other texts boxes to change their values as a result of this scrolling.

For the record, I have searched quite a bit. Also, the event actions (i.e. - mouse up, mouse down) only work when the dropdown box is first entered. Not on subsequent actions ... at least as far as I can tell. I also have `commit selected value immediately checked`, which helps because you don't have to leave the box before it fires.

Is what I want possible? Or can the scripts only run after the selection is committed?

[image: DropDown]

Answer (score 1):

Dropdown properties>Calculate>Custom calculation script. Place the script in that box for it to instantly update another place.

Use this formula in script:

```
var one = this.getField("fieldName 1").value; //fieldname 1 should be name of dropdown field//

if(one=="Administration") getField("fieldName 2").value = "Chief";<br>
if(one=="Apparatus Maintenance") getField("fieldName 2").value = "Engineer";<br>
if(one=="Confined Space") getField("fieldName 2").value = "Rescue Technician";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to fire some JavaScript whenever user changes highlighted option using **keyboard**. Because whenever a key is pressed, the OnKeyPress event of the combo is fired.

Support for mouse is trickier. When user hovers mouse pointer over an item in combo, no event is fired. The same OnKeyPress event is fired only when user actually clicks on an option.